# How to prove schedulability equation for real time scheduling?

Tags: process, operating-system, real-time, scheduling

In **andrew s tanenbaum modern operating systems** chapter two on process, under real time scheduling, it says that the schedulability of the given process is governed by the following eqauation. 
[image]

> event i occurs with period Pi and requires Ci seconds of CPU time to
>   handle each

Could someone please tell me how to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was able to worked out a solution.

if Pi is the period, then 1/Pi is the frequency. Then Ci/Pi is the time taken by i event per second. To be able to schedule all the m number of events, the Sum (Ci/Pi) should be less than or equal 1.